# Why does the UI appear different when input is nested inside label

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap forms.  I see that the UI is different when the input is nested inside a label. Can someone explain me why?

Here is the code snippet

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>userName:
            <input class="form-control col-sm-5" formControlName="userName" type="text">
       </label>  
     </div>


     <div class="form-group">
        <label>userName:</label>  
        <input class="form-control col-sm-5" formControlName="userName" type="text">    
     </div>
</form>
```

[image]

My page is rendered as shown in an image.  My question is why does the input element appear shorter in the first and longer in the second row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it`s according HTML Way of treating Codes as Block and Inline elements.

**A block-level element always starts on a new line.**

**A block-level element always takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).**

**A block level element has a top and a bottom margin, whereas an inline element does not.**

---

**An inline element does not start on a new line.**

**An inline element only takes up as much width as necessary.**

[Source 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)  [Source 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout)

and the way bootstrap treat it according to [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) theory